# Cancel multiple Alarms when Application is killed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I have set 10 sets of Alarms and I have cancelled all alarms when the application is killed  by placing it in OnDestroy method but still some Alarms are Active.I want to destroy all Alarms when the Application is killed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int id;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


        for(id=0;id<10;id++)
        {
            Long time = new GregorianCalendar()
            .getTimeInMillis()
            +10000;
            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    AlarmReciever.class);              

                         intentAlarm.putExtra("AlarmID", id);


            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    MainActivity.this, id, intentAlarm,
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time,
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            MainActivity.this, id,
                            intentAlarm,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        }

    } 

    protected void onDestroy() {


        for(id=0;id<10;id++)
        {
            Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    AlarmReciever.class);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    MainActivity.this, id, AlarmIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    super.onDestroy();

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `AlarmManager` in the first place? The *point* behind `AlarmManager` is to schedule events that you need when your app *is not running*.

Comment: My Requirement is to kill all alarms when the application is Killed.

Comment: Then do not use `AlarmManager`. Use other mechanisms that are completely inside of your process (`TimerTask`, `ScheduledExecutorService`, etc.), and then those "alarms" will go away when your process is terminated.

Comment: so is it not possible to deactivate multiple alarms when application is killed??

Comment: There are many ways in which an application can be "killed". Not all of them involve the use of `onDestroy()`. You do not necessarily get a chance to do anything when your application is "killed". This is why it is inappropriate for you to be using `AlarmManager` in your use case.

Comment: I just want to cancel all the alarms only in this case when home button is clicked and the application is killed manually.. is it possible??

Comment: what do you mean by _this case when home button is clicked and the application is killed manually_? Please explain **killed manually**

Comment: When we press long press the home button we get a list of running application ,now we can select the application from the list and drag it so that the application is killed.This process is called killed manually.After killing it manually , i wont to deactivate all the set alarms.

Comment: Well, in that specific case, `onDestroy()` should be called and your code should cancel all alarms. However, there are other cases where Ansdroid can just kill your process without calling `onDestroy()` on your activities.

Comment: In any case, please remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` from the call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. This argument should contain `PendingIntent` flags, not `Intent` flags. This is just wrong.

Comment: When the above block is placed in OnDestroy method, only some alarms are cancelled but still some alarms are still active

Comment: Well, I can't see why. Can you verify that the `onDestroy()` method is actually being called? Add some logging.

Comment: it is being called out of 10 alarms to be cancelled only 2 alarms are cancelled others are neglected i.e the ondestroy method is called only for some period of time and after that it immediately exits..

Comment: Are you saying that `onDestroy()` is being called, but it is not looping through all 10 of your alarms?

Comment: And are you sure that there is nothing in your logcat? Please make sure that you aren't filtering the logcat because you might miss something important.

Comment: yes exactly , it is not looping through 10 of the alarms. it just loops through 2 or 3 of the alarms..

Answer (score 0):

Hey for cancelling all alarms , use following snippet in your onDestroy() method :

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReciever.class);

    AlarmActivity.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, i,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context. getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    am.cancel(AlarmActivity.pendingIntent);
```

in order to cancel all alarms, run above code inside some loop with looping variable's id=1 to 10

Comment: OP is already doing this in `onDestroy()`. Why are you telling him to do what he is already doing?

Comment: Hello,but at the time when app is killed or destroyed,onDestroy() is called and that is what he's asking and look my code for cancelling alarm is different.I have succesfully implemented it in my code.Thanx

Comment: There is no relevant difference between your code and his code. The use of `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` is irrelevant here.

Comment: When the above block is placed in OnDestroy method, only some alarms are cancelled but still some alarms are still active.